# Решение задачи на javascript

Tags: javascript

Два автомобиля одновременно выехали навстречу друг другу из двух городов и встретились через 2 часа.

Первый ехал со скоростью 95км/ч, а второй 114км/ч.

Цель: Выяснить на каком расстоянии находятся города друг от друга и после всех вычеслений записать результат в переменную.

```
Исходные данные: 
time = 2;
speedOfFirst = 95;
speedOfSecond = 114;
```

Как вычеслить расстояние?

Comment: Ну а без жаваскрипта, в тетрадке, как бы решили?

Comment: https://spishu.ru/publ/domashka/matematika/dva_avtomobilja_odnovremenno_vyekhali_navstrechu_drug_drugu/39-1-0-107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time = 2;
speedOfFirst = 95;
speedOfSecond = 114;
convergenceSpeed = speedOfSecond + speedOfFirst;
// скорость сближения равна сумме скоростей встречных автомобилей
result = convergenceSpeed * time;
// если встретились через 2 часа, то скорость сближения умножаем на 2 и получим общее расстояние
alert(result);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]